# I created new instance from snapshot of wordpress instance. now default page loads as default apache page not wordpress page

Tags: apache, amazon

I had a full running wordpress site on aws lightsail. I was trying to setup two domain names to one instance using SSH. I stopped apache server and started again and site completely died.

Luckily I had created a manual snapshot two weeks back so I created new instance from snapshot of wordpress instance. now default page loads as default apache page not wordpress page on AWS using lightsail.

The default apache page load on bind static ip. domain name does not work either.

Please help to revive the site.

Answer : I finally did it. Revived my site back. It was not easy and not a single step helps. MANY steps to go through, BUT I HAVE THE SOLUTION NOW!

Comment: Did you point the domain name to the new IP address of the new instance?

Comment: Yes. Domain name is pointed to the static ip of the instance. Nothing loads if I use domain name. But default page of Apache server loads if I use the static ip address. I get - This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in domainname
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN for entering domain name

Comment: just check if simple index.php is running or not?

Comment: Check the Apache configuration and make sure you configured it to run the domain and point to the website root directory

Comment: Well I tried everything. NOTHING WORKED. But finally I worked out a way.